# Why are my Admob impression still zero?

Tags: android, admob, banner

I added banner ad unit to my android game and my players are getting ads on it but the impression count and everything else remains nil, is there anything I am missing?

Comment: try creating a new ad id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have Integrated your ad id correctly, if still not working try to create a new ad and integrate it !

Answer (score -1):

I checked and it was the issue of ID's